# CMake on windows - bug in FindOpenGL.cmake when using imported target OpenGL::GLU?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, cmake, glu

So I'm trying to use cmake on windows to build an OpenGL application, and I'm having problems linking to GLU.

Specifically, I'm using cmake 3.11's FindOpenGL.cmake to try to bring in OpenGL::GLU as an imported target, since I want to use "modern" cmake best practices.  My CMakeLists.txt has this section:

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

if(NOT TARGET OpenGL::GLU)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "GLU could not be found")
endif(NOT TARGET OpenGL::GLU)

message(STATUS "glu: ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY}")

get_target_property(GLU_IMPORTED_LIBNAME OpenGL::GLU IMPORTED_LIBNAME)
message(STATUS "glu imported libname: ${GLU_IMPORTED_LIBNAME}")
```

...and then near the end:

```
target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest PRIVATE
    ${OS_LIBRARIES}
    OpenGL::GL
    OpenGL:GLU
    GLUT::GLUT
    )
```

It seems to find GLU correctly - passes my if check for `TARGET OpenGL::GLU`, and my STATUS printouts are:

```
 -- glu: glu32
 -- glu imported libname: glu32
```

Having the libname as "just" glu32 (no .lib, no pathname) seems a bit odd, but maybe that's fine...? The weird bit is then when I try to build / link, I see this error:

```
C:\...\LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OpenGL:GLU.lib'
```

Taking a look at the generated build.ninja (I'm using the Ninja generator), I see this:

```
build OpenGLTest.exe: ...
  LINK_LIBRARIES = opengl32.lib OpenGL:GLU.lib C:\...\freeglut.lib
```

So... the `OpenGL::GL` and `GLUT::GLUT` get properly translated into real pathnames, but somehow, the `OpenGL::GLU` target gets translated into `OpenGL:GLU.lib`, which is clearly wrong.  This seems like a bug in either the way FindOpenGL.cmake is set up, or a bug in cmake itself (which seems less likely).

Has anyone else ever experienced something similar, or have any insight into what might be going on here? Should I file a bug report against cmake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in your CMake script - it should be `OpenGL::GLU`, not `OpenGL:GLU`:

```
target_link_libraries(OpenGLTest PRIVATE 
    ${OS_LIBRARIES} OpenGL::GL
    OpenGL:GLU # single colon!
    GLUT::GLUT
)
```

Comment: Wow... that is... so obvious in retrospect, it's embarassing. I want to hide in shame and delete my question, but I don't want to rob you of your points... thanks so much!